# How to use data frame in python web application code

Tags: python, web

I am trying to create a python web application to show a time series graph with gold price distribution. I have added app layout, app calls back, and update_graph function as well. after that, I tried to take a copy of my data frame and save it to a new data frame as 'dff' but it is throwing an error. Also at the end of the code, I have put 'return fig' and it is throwing an error as well. I am fairly new to python and need help to figure out what's wrong with my code. Below is the entire code.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output

from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

url = "http://goldpricez.com/gold/history/lkr/years-3"

req = Request(url=url)
html = urlopen(req).read()
df = pd.read_html(url)  # this will give you a list of dataframes from html

df1 = df[3]

first_val = df1.iloc[0][0]


date = df1[0]
price = df1[1]

data = [df1[0],df1[1]]

headers = ["Date", "Price"]

df3 = pd.concat(data, axis=1, keys=headers)


from datetime import datetime
df3['Date'] = df3['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%m-%Y'))


df3['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).year
df3['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).month
df3['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).day

df3['WDay'] = df3['Date'].dt.dayofweek

df3['WeekDayName'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3['Date']).day_name()



print(df3['WDay'])



writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()


app = dash.Dash(__name__)



app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1("Gold Price Analyst" , style={'text-align' : 'center'}),

    dcc.Graph(id='this_year_graph', figure={})








])

@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='this_year_graph', component_property='figure')]
)

def update_graph():

dff = df3.copy()
dff = [df4['Date'],df4['Price']]

fig = px.line(dff , x=dff['Date'], y=dff['Price'])

return fig

if __name__ =='__main__' :
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def update_graph():

    dff = df3.copy()
    dff = [df4['Date'],df4['Price']]

    fig = px.line(dff , x=dff['Date'], y=dff['Price'])

    return fig
```

Comment: It is working and now errors are not throwing but when I run the code I get following error app.layout = html.Div([
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'Div'

Comment: It says that whatever you calling is a byte object. Try to add the encoding to utf-8

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't get it??

Comment: Checked it right now. You are calling the HTML variable which is a byte object - print it so you will see a ,,b letter'' before the content. And the error that pops is telling you that byte object does not has a Div object - which is true because there are raw bytes. Try adding .decode('utf-8') at the end of HTML so the HTML variable will look  html = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')

Comment: Now this AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Div'

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do. What should do that function? I can think that it is looking for a div. am I right?

Comment: In my app layout I have added a graph (dcc.graph). I want it to show the date in X axis and Price in Y axis as a time series graph. Can I do this without this function I have used? "def update_graph()"

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have a rich experience with that library, I would recommend you to accept my answer as the proper one and post a new question regarding a new issue.